# Get value from List<ListObject>

Tags: java, list, object

I am interestig in how to get value from `Object` from `List<>`.
Here is code example with Objects

```
@Override
public List<ListObject> initChildren() {

    //Init the list
    List<ListObject> mObjects = new ArrayList<ListObject>();

    //Add an object to the list
    StockObject s1 = new StockObject(this);
    s1.code = "Системне програмування-1";
    s1.num = "1.";
    s1.value = "307/18";
    s1.time = "8:30 - 10:05";
    mObjects.add(s1);

    StockObject s2 = new StockObject(this);
    s2.code = "Комп'ютерна електроніка";
    s2.num = "2.";
    s2.value = "305/18";
    s2.time = "10:25 - 11:00";
    mObjects.add(s2);

    StockObject s3 = new StockObject(this);
    s3.code = "Психологія";
    s3.num = "3.";
    s3.value = "201/20";
    s3.time = "11:20 - 13:55";
    mObjects.add(s3);

    StockObject s4 = new StockObject(this);
    s4.code = "Проектування програмного забезпечення";
    s4.num = "4.";
    s4.value = "24";
    s4.time = "14:15 - 16:50";
    mObjects.add(s4);

    return mObjects;
}
```

Comment: Can you descripe what the result of your question should be? I do not understand what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get() method like follows

```
mObjects.get(index)
```

where index is the zero based index of your List, just like an array. 
To directly access object, you do for example,

```
mObjects.get(index).code
```

Answer (score 0):

you use like below

```
List<ListObject> mObjects = new ArrayList<ListObject>();

.......................your program...........

//access using enhanced for loop

for(ListObject myObj : mObjects){

System.out.println(myObj.code);

System.out.println(myObj.num);

System.out.println(myObj.value);

}
```

//access using index

```
int index=0;
 System.out.println(mObjects.get(index).code);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the collection and type cast to the data type you know its in there.

```
    List<ListObject> listOfObjects = initChildren();

    for (Iterator iterator = listOfObjects.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        StockObject so = (StockObject) iterator.next();
        // do whatever you want with your StockObject (so)
        System.out.println("Code:" + so.code);
    }
```

You can use for each syntax as well like following

```
    List<ListObject> listOfObjects = initChildren();

    for (ListObject listObject : listOfObjects) {
        StockObject so = (StockObject) listObject;
        // do whatever you want with your StockObject (so)
        System.out.println("Code:" + so.code);
    }
```